# How to tell if I'm using HFS+ or APFS?

Tags: macos, command-line, filesystem, apfs, hfs+

Using `diskutil`, or other command line tools, how can I determine which filesystem I'm using?

```
# sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion:    10.8.5
BuildVersion:    12F45
```

Comment: You are using the HFS+ filesystem. But, there is no indication if you are using core storage.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Are you able to determine this by my version number? Is there a command I can use to verify?

Comment: APFS requires ProductVersion 10.13.0 or higher. You can determine HFS+, Core Storage and APFS from the output of `diskutil list`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. What's confusing is, using the Disk Utils app, the harddrive reads "(APFS)".

Comment: Also confusing is, after encrypting the drive with FileVault and rebooting, `diskutil cs list` reports no Core Storage volumes found.

Comment: @DavidAnderson IMHO the Mac is booting from an old recovery system but the internal disk is formatted to APFS.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest way is using the **diskutil** command line as follows:

```
diskutil info /
```

You will see a report which will include something like this for an APFS formatted storage:

```
Volume Name:              Macintosh HD
Mounted:                  Yes
Mount Point:              /
Partition Type:           41504752-0000-11AA-AA23-01306543EFEA
File System Personality:  APFS
Type (Bundle):            apfs
Name (User Visible):      APFS
Owners:                   Enabled
```

See under **Type** to determine what kind of file system is on your root volume.

This will be displayed on an HFS formatted storage:

```
Volume Name:              Macintosh HD
Mounted:                  Yes
Mount Point:              /
Partition Type:           Apple_HFS
File System Personality:  Journaled HFS+
Type (Bundle):            hfs
Name (User Visible):      Mac OS Extended (Journaled)
Journal:                  Journal size 155648 KB at offset 0x3a38000
Owners:                   Enabled
```

If you want to automate this or use the results in a script, you can use following one-liner:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :FilesystemType" /dev/stdin <<< $(diskutil info -plist /)
```

Which will produce output:

```
apfs
```

or

```
hfs
```

Comment: What a strange idea, to hide a program like `PlistBuddy` in `/usr/libexec`! That's the place for programs usually run by daemons and the like, after all.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen and it is such a wonderful tool, too!

Answer (score -2):

or just launch disk utility - it will list the "Type" also

Comment: The question specifically states CLI :)

Comment: DiskUtility for an external volume: 

 "Type: USB External Physical Volume"; 

nothing about HFS or APFS

Answer (score -2):

Apple>About this Mac>System Report>Storage.

Comment: The question asks for command line tools